# Meteor/ES6 Modules - single file that imports and exports everything

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, meteor-react

I'm working on converting my Meteor app to 1.3 (rc.10) and I wanted to have a single file that imported all my components,packages,etc. that my components could import from, rather than having to type the import file paths out every time. I've seen this done before multiple times, and have done it myself with other frameworks (Backbone/requireJS).

I'm running into a problem that seems to almost be some sort of circular require/dependency because everything is undefined.

So I split it up into 2 files, one for packages (npm packages, meteor packages, etc.), and the other for my components. When I did that, the packages file worked fine, but in the components file they were still all undefined.

I have a [test repo](https://github.com/zachdixon/modules-tests) for some more clarification

Comment: Have you tried [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/)? I think you're looking for some kind of bundling tool. Correct me if that is not the case.

Comment: I'm using Meteor 1.3 which uses ES6 modules (babel) which compiles to node modules I believe (require/exports) so I don't think I should need anything else.